# Airflow DAG Task to Archive files creates recursive folders

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have the below Google GCS to GCS file move.  In Google GCS (Storage) I have a folder in my bucket (we'll call "bucket1").  In bucket1, there's an Archive Folder, and a series of json files.

I'm trying to put the json files into the Archive folder.  My problem is that it's also making a copy of the Archive folder (plus contents inside).  This is creating a recursive Archive folder (i.e. Archive\Archive\Archive....).  Here's the task:

```
archive_files = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='Archive_Files',
    source_bucket='my_data',
    source_object='*.json',
    destination_bucket='my_data',
    destination_object='Archive/',
    move_object=True,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='connection1',
    dag=dag
)
```

How do I tell Airflow, I only want the files in that folder, whithout creating a recursive "Archive" folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a task with a bash operator, the task should look like this:

```
t1 = BashOperator(
        task_id='t1',
        bash_command = f'gsutil mv gs://gcs_location/*.csv gs://gcs_location/archive/'
    )
```